# Windows service priority change really allocate more CPU utilization for that service?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, utilization

As a test, I wanted to see if a program installs faster when I set the priority of the setup.exe & msiexec.exe to `realtime`. I did not really see any significant changes in the installation process and the CTU utilization increased about 3% [based on a i7]. Is there any difference to the overall load-balanced utilization for the other services? Say it does allocate more utilization and increase the performance of that service, how does one change the priority for a specific service permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When more threads than CPU cores you have ask for CPU time the [Thread Scheduler uses the priority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (plus other factors, like how long the thread has been waiting in line) to figure out who gets to use the CPU and who has to wait their turn.

Now if no one is asking for CPU time and you have cores sitting there doing nothing changing the priority will not have very much effect on the system because the priority only really matters when there is a tie.

Also note, by setting the process priority you also affect [the priority of IO](http://bitsum.com/pl_io_priority.php) for the process too.